# what does this jinja2 Filter do in Ansible? d({})

Tags: ansible, jinja

I try to understand what the following codeblock does inside an Ansible-Playbook

```
environment: '{{ inventory__environment | d({})
                   | combine(inventory__group_environment | d({}))
                   | combine(inventory__host_environment  | d({})) }}'
```

From my understanding the `environment:` Keyword sets environment variables on the target host.
The double-moustaches `{{ xxx }}` mark a jinja2 expression - Correct me if Im wrong. So there happens some kind of evaluation of what is inside those brackets.
An Expression of the following format `{{ x | y }}` is called a 'filter'  in Ansible. It works like a pipe in Bash.

So what does this special function called `d()` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q: *"What does this special function called d() do?"*

A: `d()` is shortcut for [`default()`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables). For example the tasks below

```
    - set_fact:
        dictX: '{{ dict1 | d({}) |
                   combine(dict2 | d({})) |
                   combine(dict3 | d({})) }}'
    - debug:
        var: dictX
```

where `dict1`, `dict2`, and `dict3` are not defined give

```
    "dictX": {}
```

---

The fiter [`combine`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) combines the dictionaries. Let's test it. For example

```
  vars:

    dict1:
      key1: 'value1'
#   dict2:
#     key2: 'value2'
    dict3:
      key3: 'value3'

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        dictX: '{{ dict1 | d({}) |
                   combine(dict2 | d({})) |
                   combine(dict3 | d({})) }}'
    - debug:
        var: dictX
```

give

```
    "dictX": {
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key3": "value3"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Am I right, that your playbook would fail with an error if you didn't use the default() filter?

Comment: Correct. This is the purpose of the filer. See also very useful [default(omit)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters).